# No sound as user, with sudo it runs - 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio

Today I switched my Ubuntu from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. After this change there were no sound any more.Then I started my investigation. I found several comments in Internet but no one solved this problem. I don't know what I have to do.

I opened a terminal and then there was a not understandable situation for me.

If I write

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

there is no sound.

And if I write

```
sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

there is sound present.

Is somebody of you experienced in this matter to give me a good and helpful hint?

Is there something to be changed in group permissions?

Comment: The instructions in this post worked well for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61827981/7634896 (just the part about the "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" - I didn't need to blacklist anything)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your advice. I had already added the audio group, everything was done with pulseaudio and timidity is also outside. In the meantime I've found a work around that has completely resolved my problem with the sound. And it goes like this:

1. Log in to the terminal as the super user:

   ```bsh
   sudo su
   ```
2. Then edit the configuration file `analog-output-lineout.conf` by running:

   ```bsh
   gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf
   ```
3. In the editor, change all occurrences of `switch=off` to `switch=on`. I also changed `switch=mute` to `switch-on`.
4. Then do a restart. Lo and behold, the sound is there.

Now I'm just letting Imany improve my mood!

*Translated and slightly expanded from the [original German version](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1279451/1).*

Answer (score 0):

exactly the same problem here!
Solved by removing timidity and restarted the laptop!

```
sudo apt-get purge timidity
```

Hope it helps,

Jan

Answer (score -1):

Recently I had the same problem. It started to work after I did this:

```bsh
killall pulseaudio; pulseaudio -k  ; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

Then, after waiting 10 seconds, run:

```bsh
pulseaudio --start
```

This is the site where I found my answer to this problem:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Good luck.